Pyautogui clicking function working on my Desktop (e.g. opening directory) but not working on a game/app screen?
I have some basic Python code that uses pyautogui to move and click.
It was working yesterday, but today it doesn't seem to work anymore - in particular the clicking on the game window.
pyautogui.moveTo(495, 815)
pyautogui.click(x=495, y=815, clicks=2, interval=0.5) 

When I run this code on my desktop, and double click on a directory, it works fine.
But when I run it against a game window, the clicking doesn't take effect.
Is there a workaround, and if not is there an alternative to pyautogui for automating mouse clicks?
